# Difference between SignData() and CreateSignature() in .NET Cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

Basically, what is the difference between the two:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.SignData(..)
```

and

```
RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(...)
```

Both at the end of the day sign the message, difference being that `SignData` computes the hash value and then signs, whereas `CreateSignature` already requires hashed message, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of both should be identical.

The first one, `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, provides a high level API. The actual software implementation is hidden. This way the API can also be used with special hardware such as a smart card; the provider is just a front end for an actual implementation. It may not take a pre-calculated hash-value because the hardware may not offer that kind of functionality. Finally, the API could also be used for signatures that use PSS padding - if an implementation of PSS is available.

The second one, `RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter` provides only part of the functionality. For instance, it doesn't offer the hashing part of the calculation and it doesn't perform signature *verification*. Very likely it is used for the *implementation of RSACryptoServiceProvider in managed code*. It's part of a lower level API that directly implements cryptographic primitives.

> ... difference being that SignData computes the hash value and then signs, whereas CreateSignature already requires hashed message, is this correct?

Yes, even though the description of `rgbHash` reads "data to be signed", this is just **another** fuckup by the .NET documentation. The [example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t695azzk(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) makes it clear that the bytes *of the hash* are indeed required, rather than the message itself. The signature generation includes hashing the data, so describing it as "data to be signed" is plain wrong.

Comment: Indeed, the output is identical

Answer (score 2):

`RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter` is part of an object API to allow the separation of "I want this to be signed" and "I know what kind of signature I want".  The `CreateSignature` method for it just calls RSA.SignHash ([with a bit of reflection overload magic](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsapkcs1signatureformatter.cs,7372133810b165a8)).

RSA.SignData just [computes the hash of the input and calls RSA.SignHash](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsa.cs,cfdb5f5043f89be3).

So the idea, sort of, is that if you know that you have an RSA key and you are doing an RSA signature, just use the RSA class.  If you're a generic component, like SignedCms or SignedXml, you might take an `AsymmetricFormatter` and then just provide it with the data to get your signature.  In practice, though, there ends up being too much context around the signature for those classes to be generally useful.  CMS, X.509 and xmldsig all have different contextual data that is required, and the `AsymmetricFormatter` and `AsymmetricDeformatter` classes don't really help.  So they haven't been added to with ECDSA, RSA-PSS, and FIPS 186-3's revisit of DSA.